# when i call geolocation for currentlocation.I am facing error like this

Tags: angularjs, ionic3

when i call geolocation for currentlocation.I am facing error like this

```
 TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
 at Geolocation.getCurrentPosition 

import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
     constructor(public geolocation:Geolocation ){}
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
     // resp.coords.latitude
     // resp.coords.longitude
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
```

Comment: because `getCurrentPosition` is not a function and you are calling it as `getCurrentPosition()` , its an object(as per your error). Try to put console.log and check

Comment: have you upgrade your ionic cli to version 4 or above?

Comment: my ionic version is 3.9.2

Comment: I have the same problem !!!!!

Comment: You should try https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/diagnostic/ plugin with ionic v3 and  with isLocationEnabled() function in diagnostic plugin you can force user to enable GPS, after that you can use  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
Hope this will help.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

i tried to arrange the code, because I think the problem in the  code

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private geolocation: Geolocation) { 

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.onSuccess, this.onError);
    }
      onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
      'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
     }
     onSuccess(position) {
     let element = document.getElementById('map');
     element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
                  'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' +
                  '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;
                  console.log(element)
     }
```

if that not work you can see this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/geolocation-issues/157072/7

also, you can see the tutorial here
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation#coords